# Moving Active Admin index view into its own index.html.arb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to move out some of the logic for the index/show/edit pages into their own view files. This is because my ActiveAdmin files are just getting to large and overwhelming.

At the moment I have active admin page like:

```
# /admin/products.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :name
  end
end
```

I want to move the index logic into a file like:

```
#/views/admin/products/index.html.arb
index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column :name
end
```

is this possible? I can't seem to find any docs or StackOverflow questions about it. Has anyone tried and done this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so you'll have to create a file under   `views/admin/products/_index.html.whatever_extention`

This view should use [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) syntax, because it's what AA use for views generation.

Than, lastly, in index block render this partial:

```
index do
  render partial: 'index'
end
```

Comment: thanks! thats perfect. Any idea how to add the 'actions' in the table? I'm moving the table to its own partial, but I still want to have the 'view' 'edit' and 'delete' links in the table.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you'll still have access to AA helpers, so just add these links with corresponding paths and it should work.

Comment: I had to do a slightly funky around (making an array of the links and then joining them) but it works fine. Not quite as nice as just adding 'actions' but hey!